# Twig Error Unknown "format_number" filter on Symfony 4 project

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony4, twig-filter

format_number was introduced in 2.12, as far as I can tell I have 2.13, using `{{ constant('Twig_Environment::VERSION') }}` outputs `The current version is 2.13.0`

Here is my composer json, I just dont see a reason I should be getting an unknown filter in this symfony 4.4.* project.

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "beberlei/doctrineextensions": "^1.2",
        "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "^2.3",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.4",
        "symfony/asset": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/console": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/form": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/orm-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.2",
        "symfony/twig-bridge": "4.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/validator": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/web-server-bundle": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "4.4.*",
        "twig/twig": "2.*"
    },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`format_number` filter is not part of the main `twig/twig` package. You need the Twig Extra package/bundle which you can install with:

```
composer require twig/extra-bundle twig/intl-extra
```

Comment: Always the little things that get you. Had to also get `composer require twig/intl-extra`

Comment: You're right. I overlooked that it is only in `require-dev` section of `twig/extra-bundle`.

Comment: also needed `$environment->addExtension(new IntlExtension());`